# Sitecore publishing restrictions by language

Tags: sitecore, publishing

In Sitecore, the publishing restrictions access via the dialog are stored under the inherited *Publish* base template - for example, the Item-level *Publishable* checkbox is stored under `__Never publish`.

I had expected to be able to restrict publishing by language, but the fields above are shared between languages so apply to all.

Obviously I could unshare the fields, but I'm not sure what other implications there may be. Has anyone tried this or implemented another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the publishing of an item by language, but it is **also by version**. These are stored in the `Lifetime` field section, rather than the `Publishing` section.

This will allow you to mark a specific version in a specific language as *unpublishable*, however it won't affect *all* versions in that language.

Other than that, an option would be to add a new field to a base template that is Unversioned, perhaps "Publishable In Language". You could then look into adding a new step into the `publishItem` pipeline that takes this into account when determining whether a version is to be published - this would possibly take place just after the `DetermineAction` step, where Sitecore uses its own logic to determine if an item is to be published. Unfortunately that class isn't easily overridable and uses private methods, so it's not a great candidate for extension itself.